# In what situation can the U.S. military use nukes without the consent of the President?

Tags: united-states, military, nuclear-weapons

In what situation can the U.S. military use nukes without the consent of the President, if any situation like this exists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, the decision is reserved for the President as *Commander in Chief*. All other conditions are to assure secure communications and the rule of succession.

- The Vice President can only decide if the President is (temporarily or permanently) unable to decide. The [25th Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) and the [Presidential Succession Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_Succession_Act#Table_of_statutory_successors) define the order of succession.
- There might be a breakdown of communications which leaves the US military unable to contact the President or his or her lawful successor. In the past, the US president [pre-delegated launch authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Integrated_Operational_Plan#Prevention_versus_preemption) to the military if certain conditions were fulfilled.
- There is the custom of having a *designated survivor* away from mass gatherings of the President and most other successors. If something were to happen that kills or incapacitates the President, but leaves a person higher up than the designated survivor alive, then that person higher up is in charge. The *designated survivor* is just someone in the line of succession who has been briefed and put in touch with strategic communications.
- Today a confirmation of a launch order by a second individual is required. As I understand it, this does not in any way limit the authority of the *Commander in Chief*, it is merely a procedure to authenticate the integrity of the launch orders.
- There are media reports that during the last days of the Nixon presidency, cabinet officials [conspired](https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2017/08/11/donald-trump-nuclear-weapons-richard-nixon-215478/) to take the solitary launch ability away from the President. That was arguably <strike>treason</strike> criminal, but push never came to shove.

Comment: What if a US nuclear submarine cannot reach anyone in the command structure? For example, [UK submarines have written orders from the PM which are to be opened in case](https://www.bbc.com/news/newsbeat-36824917) they can't reach anyone in the UK. Does the US not have such orders?

Comment: @JJJ, that would be another case for my second bullet point. But the US considered their communications more survivable than the British ones -- London was much closer to the Soviet Union.

Comment: @JJJ: US SSBN warheads have [Permissive Action Links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permissive_Action_Link) and will not detonate without authorisation codes that aren't on board the submarine. So the US relies on its communications, and spends a lot of money on them. The UK can't afford such a communication system, so they don't use PALs and the subs could launch independently. They're just trusted not to do so.

Comment: @JohnDallman, as I understand it a PAL primarily makes sure that a missile warhead will only explode after a missile launch and missile flight (and not in the tube or in the back of a van). For subs, the communication system makes sure that the crew can know if they should turn the key or not.

Comment: @o.m.: That's safety fusing, not the PAL. See the link.

Comment: @JohnDallman, I had thought of the environmental sensing device as part of the PAL. But it seems it doesn't have to be to make a PAL a PAL.

Comment: "That was arguably treason, but push never came to shove." Strictly speaking, disloyalty by someone to prevent them from carrying out a war against a country that the nation isn't currently at war with isn't treason (as define in the constitution), although I'm sure that it would be a crime of some sort.

Comment: @o.m.: Of course, if you have physical access to the weapon, one can always bypass the security systems given some effort.